# Cleaning up nested mod_rewrite statements

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am cleaning up a large `.htaccess` file containing a lot of `mod_rewrite` statements.

The biggest part of the clutter comes from statements catching various occurrences of

```
/directory1
/directory1/directory2
/directory1/directory2/directory3
```

using statements like

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$   
RewriteRule .* /front.php?level1=%1&level2=%2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$   
RewriteRule .* /front.php?level1=%1&level2=%2&level3=%3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

could somebody versed with mod_rewrite give me a pointer on how to write one universal statement that will catch any depth of `directory1/directory2...` and put the appropriate `level` variable into the RewriteRule?

Comment: This question belongs to serverfault.

Comment: Naaah, come on. There are tons of mod_rewrite related questions on SO.

Comment: Before or after being serverfault online?

Comment: Belongs on Serverfault. Some people haven't woken up to it, but Mod_Rewrite does in fact belong on Serverfault.

Comment: We are discussing all sorts of HTML questions by the *truckload* on SO, a lot of which would *really* belong on Doctype. Using mod_rewrite is usually a part of optimizing or building a sensible URL structure for a dynamic web site. How is that *not* programming related?

Comment: @Chacha102 and @FerranB see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use the following rewriterule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front.php/$1 [L]
```

and access folders by pathinfo in `front.php`:

```
$pathinfo = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

You can alternatively also enable `MultiViews` in Apache and configure it to use `front.php` as index file instead and grab pathinfo the same way.

Comment: Good idea, and no problem performance wise because what gets caught by this, will be run through the PHP script no matter what. This will be an application built to run on as many platforms as possible, so I don't want to have a dependency on MultiViews. What I'm using now is `RewriteRule ^dirname/(.*)$ dirname/index.php?request=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` Cheers!